# proper way to echo image data from php for Jquery consumption

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

I have a php function which is called by a jquery function.  This jquery function will essentially place the picture on the page.  I am having a hard time getting this to work right.  I am trying to pin down where he problem might lie... My current line of thinking is that I am not sending the data back to my jquery function properly.  Here is how I am getting the image

```
 if(mysql_query("insert into Personal_Photos (Email, Pics) values('$email', '$data')"))
 {
     $query="select Pics, MAX(ID) from Personal_Photos where Email='$email'";
     $result=mysql_query($query) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64'.base64_encode($row['Pics']).'"/>';
 }
```

The key line is right here...

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['Pics']).'"/>';
```

I am wondering if I am doing that incorrectly?  How do you do it?  Is there a better way to do it.  If you notice anything else wrong with my code, I would definitely appreciate the criticism.

Comment: why keep images in a database? why not keep them as files?

Comment: This is basically a proof of concept sort of thing.  We don't have access to all the folders on our servers, and we didn't feel like messing with IT to give us the permissions.  We do in fact have a mysql DBMS however.

Comment: but you have access to A folder on your server?

Comment: I do have access to a folder on the server.

Comment: It would probably be better to store the images as files in that folder, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
```

You need a comma after the `base64`, which your code block doesn't appear to have (though your individual line you posted has it). Which way is it in your real code?

Comment: In my code I actually have the comma.  What I posted here must have been in an un-update code store.

Comment: If I could get a reference or a link to tutorial, I think I would be in a good position.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate this query from the container webpage.
I'm not sure if there is a better way, but it's certain that my way is much simpler.

page.html:

```
<img src="img.php" />
```

img.php:

```
<?php
$img=getimg();//get the img binary from mysql and don't base64 it.
echo $img;
?>
```

Comment: Will that cause a non-ajax post to the server?  And why no base64?

Comment: It has nothing to do with ajax or post. Making `img.php` independ is more flexible, you can later add ajax or cache support, change sql query without touching the main page. But with bas64, you can just imagine how complicated it will be.